# Mysql, complex ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

Two columns town and priority.

I need to sort table, so that towns with priority=1 would be first and not sorted by name ASC, while the rest gets sorted by name ASC.

How would i do that?

Thanks ;)

**Update**

```
SELECT *
FROM map_towns
ORDER BY priority DESC, town
```

Like this, but so that priority were from 1 to 12+ instead of 12 to 1.

Like that:

```
town priority
b_town1 1
a_town2 2
d_town3 3
c_town4 4
a_town5 NULL
b_town6 NULL
c_town7 NULL
d_town8 NULL
```

etc...

Comment: Why don't you add your table structure and a sample of the result you want... I'm nit sure I understand your question fully.

Comment: ORDER BY priority, town ?????

Comment: I re-read the question a second time after I posted my answer. Do you only care about priority = 1? or should priority=1 be sorted before priority=2 and so on? For example, if "a_town2" get priority=4 and "c_town4" get priority=2, which comes first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By default, MySQL sorts nulls first](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html)

I created a small test case (rows inserted non-sorted on purpose).

```
create table map_towns(
   town varchar(30) not null
  ,priority int null
);

insert into map_towns(town, priority) values('d_town3', 3);
insert into map_towns(town, priority) values('a_town2', 2);
insert into map_towns(town, priority) values('c_town4', 4);
insert into map_towns(town, priority) values('b_town1', 1);
insert into map_towns(town, priority) values('b_town6', NULL);
insert into map_towns(town, priority) values('d_town8', NULL);
insert into map_towns(town, priority) values('a_town5', NULL);
insert into map_towns(town, priority) values('c_town7', NULL);
```

The following query should do what you ask for.

```
select town
      ,priority
      ,isnull(priority) 
 from map_towns 
order by isnull(priority), priority, town;

+---------+----------+------------------+
| town    | priority | isnull(priority) |
+---------+----------+------------------+
| b_town1 |        1 |                0 |
| a_town2 |        2 |                0 |
| d_town3 |        3 |                0 |
| c_town4 |        4 |                0 |
| a_town5 |     NULL |                1 |
| b_town6 |     NULL |                1 |
| c_town7 |     NULL |                1 |
| d_town8 |     NULL |                1 |
+---------+----------+------------------+
```

Here is a link on [ISNULL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull)

Comment: Damn yea! Just what i wanted. How could i forgot about ISNULL statement... So basically we are iterating through result to generate flags and then sort by them. Thanks mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

My idea:

```
SELECT * FROM Towns
ORDER BY IF(priority = 1, 0, 1) ASC,
         town ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well just simply make it so that the Priority by default is 0, and then each Town you have you can sort them based on a number.  I would normally do something like DisplayOrder which in terms could be your Priority.

something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Towns
ORDER BY priority ASC,
name ASC;
```

So if you have something like

```
id, name, priority
-----------------------
1, Smithtown, 0
2, Rocktown, 2
3, Georgetown, 1
4, Rockton, 2
```

The ordering then would be

```
1, Smithtown, 0
3, Georgetown, 1
4, Rockton, 2
2, Rocktown, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    map_towns
ORDER BY
        priority IS NULL, priority, town
```

Comment: Yea, but "priority <> 1" sorted list is in the end of the list, but need to be first in the list. Thanks thou mate ;)

Comment: @Beck: `priority <> 1` will evaluate to `1` for the towns with `priority` not equal to one which will place them after those with `priority = 1`. Isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: It's not placing them after, that's the problem. Everything else is working fine. I need priority > 1 be the first in list.

Comment: @Beck: So you want `priority > 1` or `priority = 1` to be first? You question reads *so that towns with priority=1 would be first*.

Comment: That's right, towns with priority > or == 1 first and rest is after. It's actually doesn't matter where they are as long as they have the right order, because i'm looping through on client side to separate them.

Comment: @Beck: what is the rest? Negative or zero priority?

Comment: I have updated first post with an example of results i need. Take a look at a,b,c,d and priority.

Comment: Ok nvm, i have sorted that out on client side.